# Bucle de X a Y especificado por el usuario

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Quiero realizar un ciclo que imprime los números del rango especificado por el usuario, por ejemplo:

- para los valores: 2 y 10, se imprime en el div: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10.

```js
function loopChecking() {
'use strict';
var numberA = document.getElementById("numberA").value,
    numberB = document.getElementById("numberB").value,
    i = 0,
    result = "";

for (i = numberA; i <= numberB; i += 1) {
    result += i + " ";
}
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Loop</title>
    <script src="numbers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="numberA" />
    <input type="text" id="numberB" />
    <input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="loopChecking()" />
    <div id="numbers"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

PD:

- [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528695/loop-in-javascript-from-x-to-y)
- Recomiendo no ejecutar, se buclea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `value` del `input` va a ser un valor de tipo `String`, debes convertirlo a valores numéricos para poder operar con ellos como números.

Mira este ejemplo.

Utilizo el método `parseInt` para convertir los valores de los `input` a enteros.

Después compruebo que el resultado de ambos haya sido un valor numérico correcto antes de continuar usando la función `isNaN`.

```js
function loopChecking() {
'use strict';
var numberA = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberA").value,10),
    numberB = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberB").value,10),
    i = 0,
    result = "";
// Comprobamos que sean valores numéricos correctos
if (isNaN(numberA) || isNaN(numberB)) return;

for (i = numberA; i <= numberB; i += 1) {
    result += i + " ";
}
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Loop</title>
    <script src="numbers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="numberA" />
    <input type="text" id="numberB" />
    <input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="loopChecking()" />
    <div id="numbers"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te añadí el `radix parameter` al parseInt